# 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. - Windows 7

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm new here to Typescript and I'm trying to install it globally on my machine.

I currently have the following versions:
Node v.11.13.0
npm v6.7.0

When I run **npm install -g typescript** I get the following results:

> C:\Users[userid].node_modules_global\tsc ->
>   C:\Users[userid].node_modules_glob al\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
>   C:\Users[userid].node_modules_global\tsserver ->
>   C:\Users[userid].node_modules
>   _global\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
>   + typescript@3.4.2 updated 1 package in 3.297s

The moment I run **tsc** or **tsc -v** on my command line, I receive the

> 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I have uninstalled node and reinstalled it, but I still get the same error.

I have consulted Google and followed other methods on Stackoverflow to fix this problem, including checking the PATH folder structure.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, please help.
FYI I am running a Windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 1):

In your command prompt, try executing the below command,

```
set path=%PATH%;c:\Users\YOUR_USER_DIRECTORY\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

Then try executing your `tsc` command again, you will get it executed now.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have entered that command you gave me into my command prompt and afterwards I ran the tsc command again. It still gives me the same error as above

Comment: The `YOUR_USER_DIRECTORY` that I mentioned should be your windows user name. Did you change that?

Comment: Yes I did change that, no luck. Also where should the PATH variable be set at?

Comment: Okay, Under your `....Roaming\npm;` directory, Do you find `tsc` and `tsc.cmd` files?

Comment: No, I do not find it there. Instead in ...Roaming\npm\node_modules\ I am finding a typescript folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191530/discussion-between-david-r-and-quentin-gerard).

Comment: I have this same issue, the typescript installationi doesn't crate a tsc.cmd which is the issue, Nothing to do the paths.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!

Ok so I dug around and discovered the following:
Under `User\[pc_name]\.node_modules_global` I found the `tsc` and `tsc.mcd` files. All I did was copy those two files across to `...\Roaming\npm`.
After doing that I ran `tsc` in my command prompt and it worked!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, but can't find a folder at 'User \ [pc_name] \.node_modules_global', any suggestions here?

Comment: Whilst this may work for you, it shouldn't be a required fix imo.